# Plugin system with events or hooks?

Tags: php, events, architecture, hook

I've created a plugin system for a software in php. In order for a plugin to alter the behaviour of the programm I wrote this (simplified) code:

```
class PluginController {

  /* ... */

  public function addHook($name, $function, $priority = 10) {
    /* store the function callback $function  associated with $name */
  }

  public function executeHook($name, $args = array()) {
    /* execute all function callbacks associated with $name
     * in order of their priority and return their results */    
  }
}
```

So plugins can add callbacks using `addHook` and somewhere in the application these callbacks get executed by calling `executeHook`.

This works quite well, but after reading some time about the topic, I'm still unsure if this technique is a *event-* or a *hook-* system.

Some sources say the difference has to do with loose and tight coupling.
Others say that hooks has return values, and events not. And others again say that events are for handlig asynchronous activity, and hooks just to inject code at some point.

So again, is the above code about *events* or *hooks*, and can someone explain the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is more like an Event.

**Hooks** allow a plugin to interact with the code that called it. They are called with the assumption that data will be returned, and the originating code will usually loop through the returned data immediately after calling the hook.

**Events**, on the other hand, are only called to announce when a particular action has taken place. They give plugins an opportunity to run their own event-handling logic at that point, without directly affecting the originating code in any way.

[Source](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-and-events)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see elements of both definitions in the above logic. The origination code can be affected because with `executeHook` arguments can be passed to the callback. These arguments can be objetcts that may be manipulated in the callback (e.g. a database querybuilder), and by doing that affect the originating code.

Comment: @MarioA hooks are smaller than events, they simply get data and change it, but events are more complicated and can do lots of things

Comment: I think I understand better now but let me explain in my own words. So hooks have a clearly defined task and return value (and thus are more tightly coupled to the application), while a event listener may execute any kind of code, there are no expectaitions to the listener by the application. Correct?